# Unwanted page refreshing in Angular SPA

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have Angular routing setup using HTML5 mode like so:

```
app.config($routeProvider, $locationProvider){

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

  $routeProvider.when("/", {
    templateUrl: "/views/login.html"
  }).when("/dashboard", {
    templateUrl: "/views/dashboard.html"
  })

});
```

Now I move between routes with simple links like this:

```
<a href="/dashboard"></a>
```

This works fine, except I seem to get a full page reload when I click the link. Angular isn't meant to do this so I'm not sure what's going on.

It may be worth noting that in reality my script is substantially more complicated than this, but having debugged everything, I can't see anything wrong other than the fact that I recently switched to the HTML5 mode.

How do I stop the page reload?

Comment: Add a `#` before your link: `<a href="#/dashboard"></a>`

Comment: @devqon I'm using HTML5 mode to get rid of the hashes. Adding hashes in will also mess with some SEO modules I have.

Comment: I've got SEO working great on another SPA using HTML5 mode in Angular. Just not sure what's going wrong here.

Comment: @devqon that statement is not true. There are numerous ways to make an SPA SEO friendly

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`ui-sref`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref) directive. It will use [`$state`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#state-1) service to load a page.

```
<a ui-sref="yourroute">Link</a>
```

You have to configure your routes with [`$stateProvider`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stateprovider-1) to use route names.

Comment: I've always used href with Angular links. Had that working for a long time. Also, just tried `ui-sref` and that broke it even more. It doesn't even go to the page anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Angular routing your link should start with a hash to prevent the browser from navigating away from the page. Have you tried:

```
<a href="#/dashboard"></a>
```